# Timer label button click android

Tags: android, multithreading

In my UI I have a button and a label.
On the button click I want to start a new thread which would update the label text to display the timer information (like 00:00 seconds).
This should be updated every second.

Could someone give a simple solution to this problem please?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the information is in the form of a textView (called tv), you would use a countdowntimer:

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1) {
 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
     mTextField.setText(/* Whatever you want for each millisecond */);
 }

 public void onFinish() {
     mTextField.setText("00:00");
 }
}.start();
```

the second parameter in the CountDownTimer constructor is the intervals for which onTick, so for this timer, onTick will be called every millisecond.

Any questions?

Comment: Hi thanks for responding.. Actually I need a stopwatch.. my bad.. Here is the code I have so far